# List all pages into one template

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I've trying to write an `if statement` in WordPress, which says: *If there are pages following this template, list them all here (title only)*

It's for a "services" section on a website following the services template. I want to do this, so, if the client adds more services at a later date they will automatically showed in the listing.

So far I have:

```
<ul>
<?php if ( is_page_template( 'template-services.php' ) ) : ?>
  <li><?php wp_title(); ?></li>
<?php endif ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `meta_query` of `WP_Query`. The template name is stored in the database `post_meta` table with the key name `wp_page_template`.

Somethings like this can be done:

```
$arg = array( 
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'meta_query' => array(
         array(
               'key' => '_wp_page_template',
               'value' => 'template-services.php'
           )
         )
        );
  $list_pages = new WP_Query($args);

  if($list_pages -> have_posts()){
     while ($list_pages->have_posts()){
       $list_pages -> the_post();
       the_title();
   } 
  }
```